# cordova android google maps simulate location on device

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, location, simulation

I have been trying to simulate location on an Android build of a Cordova application with no success. I'm using the standard Cordova Geolocation plugin.
I have added the following permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" tools:ignore="MockLocation" />
```

I've also installed the Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-mock-location, from which the success callback returns with false, telling me mock locations arent enabled.
On my Android 7.0 device there's no "allow mock locations" option in the developer options, however I can select the app which uses mock locations. I've tried "my application" / "none" but neither work and I'm unsure whether this would make a difference anyway.

When using the Android Device Monitor with my usb connected device, the "Emulator controls" -> "location controls" is disabled.
Also, likely my own fault but I can't figure out how to telnet to the application running on the usb connected device to send the `geo fix -82.411629 28.054553` type commands. However I ran the application on an Android virtual device and could telnet to it. On sending location updates to the Google maps app, they came through however my application does not respond to mock locations.

I'd really appreciate any help in getting this working!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. I built the application on the phone. (Android KitKat)
2. Closed my application
3. Enabled the GPS in the phone settings
4. Make sure that the phone caught the GPS signal
5. Launched Locito (program for location simulation, available in google play)
6. Open my application.
7. Enjoy the result =)